# Upload files in blobstore without the form

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to upload files to google app engine blobstore, the method in the google documentation requires a form , but i want to upload them without a form i.e  there are some pdf's in a folder , how can i upload them automatically to blobstore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uploaded images using the http client library with Python 2.7
The trick is to first create the redirect url then upload the image file (pdf should be similar)

```
import json
import urllib2
import MultipartPostHandler

import httplib, urllib

data2 = ""

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("localhost", 8080)
conn.request("GET", "/get_blobstore_url/")
r1 = conn.getresponse()
print r1.status, r1.reason

data2 = r1.read()

params = {'file':open('test_mat.jpg', 'rb')}
opener = urllib2.build_opener(MultipartPostHandler.MultipartPostHandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

print data2
req = urllib2.Request(data2, params)

response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read().strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use google drive and access the drive folder in GAE and write the files to the blobstore. But you have to add your folder to Google drive.

Using Google drive you can upload all your files automaticly. A user does not have to select the files.
But if you have the user has to select the files, you need a form to :

- select the files
- and pass the upload url to the user (form)

You can also create your own dropbox like service. See this blogpost : http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/Implementing-a-dropbox-service-with-the-Blobstore-API-part-3-Multiple-upload-support

Comment: thats not the solution in my case, I want to upload all files from a folder in my PC directly to GAE blobstore.

Comment: due to some reasons i cant use google drive , i have to upload files directly to GAE blobstore.